# Generating 40 random intervals with a min/max and fixed time

Tags: javascript, intervals

I'm making a game where the total game time is 180 seconds, and in those 180 seconds **40** items need to appear at **random times**. Sounds easy right? There's a catch: **The minimum delay between items can't be smaller than 1 second, and can't be higher than 10 seconds.**

So what I got so far is this:

```js
const config = {};
config.squidAppearances = 40;

const spawnTimeLastSquid = 180 - 2;
const fixedDelay = spawnTimeLastSquid / config.squidAppearances;
// Fixed delay would be 4.5
const maxDiff = Math.floor(fixedDelay);

let values = [];
let squidIntervals = [];

for (let i = 0; i < (config.squidAppearances); ++i) {
  // Here's the formula:
  const plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
  const offset = Math.random() * maxDiff * plusOrMinus;
  let current = (fixedDelay * i + offset);

  if (values.length > 1) {
    var prev = values[values.length - 1];
    if ((current - prev) > 10) current = prev - 10;
    if ((current - prev) < 1) current = prev + 1;
    // I'm saving the delay for each squid so I can do setTimeout()
    squidIntervals.push(current - prev);
  } else {
    // Spawn time would be this:
    squidIntervals.push(fixedDelay * i + offset);
  }
  // Save values so we can use the previous value on next iteration
  values.push(current);
}
// Last squid delay
squidIntervals.push(180 - spawnTimeLastSquid);

console.log(values);
```

(or as [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z2md5ua/2/))

Check your console, you will get very varied results each time you run it. Sometimes it looks like its working, but most other times the spawn times are not spread out between 0 (seconds) and 180, or the delay is 1000 for each item in the array.

What do I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

Generate interval [1;10] for every squid, calculate total time, which is usually > 180, so now you can decrease random interval till duration limit met:

```js
function generateObjects() {
    let r = [];
    let s = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<40; i++) {
        let d = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
        r[i] = d;
        s += d; // total duration
    }
    while (s >= 180.) {
        let d = Math.random();
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*40);
        if (r[i]-d >= 1.0) {
            r[i] -= d;
            s -= d;
        }
    }
    // to be sure here you could have similar to above while (s < 180.) loop and increase random interval to fully fill 180 seconds, if you want
    return r;
}

function drawObjects(objs) {
    let c = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d', {alpha: false});

    c.fillStyle = 'whitesmoke';
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 360, 10);

    c.fillStyle = 'black';
    let s = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
        s += objs[i];
        c.fillRect(2*s, 0, 1, 10);
    }
}

drawObjects(generateObjects());
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="10"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks (to everyone) for helping! I upvoted this one because I like it the best. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Franky no problem, ping me with link to game if you're planning to publish it - I'd love to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my take on it.
You can copy paste it into console and see the output.( first output is undefined which is ok );

```
let secondsFromStart;
let secondsFromAnotherItem;
setInterval(() => {
    if (typeof secondsFromStart !== 'undefined') secondsFromStart++;
    if (typeof secondsFromAnotherItem !== 'undefined') secondsFromAnotherItem++;
}, 1000);
createItem = () => {
  console.log('random item created at ' + secondsFromStart + ' seconds from the start of the game and ' + secondsFromAnotherItem + 'seconds since last item was created');
  secondsFromAnotherItem = 0;
  if (typeof secondsFromStart === 'undefined') secondsFromStart = 0;
}
generateRandomItem = (min, max) => {
    let timeout = Math.floor((Math.random() * (min - max)) + max);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (secondsFromStart > 180) {
            reject('Time is up');
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                createItem();
                generateRandomItem(min, max);
            }, timeout);// worst case scenario - item is created at last second
        }, min);// dont even start the clock until minimum time has passed
    });
}
generateRandomItem(1000, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is in this lines

```
if ((current - prev) > 10) current = prev - 10;
if ((current - prev) < 1) current = prev + 1;
```

it should work if you change to

```
if ((current - prev) > 10) current = current- 10;
if ((current - prev) < 1) current = current + 1;
```

thanks